# Multi Site Manager - File Upload Preferences - Unique per site

Tags: multi-site-manager, file-uploads

Apologies if the Title is a bit odd sounding.

Basically, I have MSM with 4 sites. Within each site is a UI file upload preference. Now when I 'Search By Directory' on the File Manager, I get UI, UI, UI and UI. - Can I get it to filter by directories only on that site? Or is the only option to give them Unique names?

Thanks,
Joe